# Loop table rows in Access, with or without use of Private Const

Tags: vba, ms-access, loops

I am doing some VBA programming here, and I have a `Private Const` with two elements as follows:

```
Private Const myList as String = "foo;bar"
```

I then have a looping structure like this:

```
myTerms = Split(myList,";")
For I = 0 to UBound(myTerms)
   'do stuff in here
Next I
```

Finally, here is the new part.  In tblWords there are 100 different row, consisting of simply an ID field, and a text field such as `tblWords.ID` and `tblWords.Word`.

My question is:  Instead of using the `Private Const` and looping twice, how can I modify my loop so that it will instead loop over the `tblWords` 100 times, once for each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblWords")

Do While Not rs.EOF
   sid = rs!ID
   sword = rs!word

   ''And to change a word
   rs.Edit
   rs!Word = rs!Word & " edited"
   rs.Update

   rs.MoveNext
Loop
```