# Excel VBA SQL from Access no results

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Using Excel 2010 to query an Access 2010 Database (via UserForms).

When I execute the code, I get my Message Box "No Results" (called near the end of the sub). However, there should be 12 records that pull up when I enter in a certain search string.

I thought maybe my SQL string was incorrect so I wrote the SQL statement to Sheet1 Cell A2. I then opened up my Access Database, created a SQL query, and copy/pasted the SQL statement from cell A2 - It worked perfectly. --> So it's not the SQL statement.

Why is my code not finding the data? The SQL statement works fine. I'm not getting any errors when I try to establish an ADODB connection.

**EDIT**: *I use the exact same database connection setup in another sub and it works fine.*

```
Private Sub searchAllInJobs(searchStr As String)
    Dim con As Object, rs As Object, accessFile As String, strTable As String, sql As String, keyStr As String, i As Integer

    accessFile = "******************"  '<--hidden on purpose

    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Failed database connection", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFile

    'Wild card string
    keyStr = """*" & searchStr & "*"""

   'I have tested this SQL statement in the Access database and works great
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_job_tables WHERE ([MODELNO] LIKE " & keyStr & ");"
    'Write the SQL to a cell, to make sure the statement was constructed properly
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").value = sql

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    'Open the database recordset from the SQL statement
    rs.Open sql, con

    'Clear the current ListBox
    Me.list_SearchJobs.Clear

    i = 0

    If Not (rs.EOF and rs.BOF) Then
        'Move to the first item
        rs.MoveFirst

        'While going through the records, if you haven't reached the End-of-file then...
         Do While Not rs.EOF

            With Me.list_SearchJobs
               .AddItem
                   .List(i, 0) = rs!JOB_NUM
                   .List(i, 1) = rs!customer
                   .List(i, 2) = rs!MODELNO
                   .List(i, 3) = rs!CREATE_DATE
            End With
            i = i + 1
            rs.MoveNext
         Loop

         'Close the recordset and database connection
         rs.Close
         con.Close

         'Set the objects to "Nothing" (clears the cache)
         Set rs = Nothing
         Set con = Nothing

    Else
        'Close the recordset and database connection
        rs.Close
        con.Close

        'Set the objects to "Nothing" (clears the cache)
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set con = Nothing

        MsgBox "No Results", vbCritical, "No results"
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your error message re a failed connection is actually being generated if you can't create the ADODB.Connection **object**, not if it can't connect to the database.  Move the `con.Open` statement before you do the test to see if it could be opened, and then let us know if you get a "Failed database connection" message.

Comment: Good catch. And no, the error was not generated. Thank you for catching that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know why this is happening. The wildcard in Access is `*`, but for most other variants of SQL it is `%`. You are using ADO here. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634506/like-operator-works-in-ms-access-but-not-ado)

Try this instead:

`keyStr = "%" & searchStr & "%" 'Not sure if you need the extra "'s either`

Comment: You are right. And what's weird is that i used to use the "%" but in Access 2010, the wildcard is actually the asterisk "*". I wonder why they are so different